# How to unit test PHP REST API?

Tags: php, rest, api, unit-testing, travis-ci

I mean I know I can write [PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/) tests,
but **how to mock web server / mysql server**?

I'd also like to test MySQL / database code.
Best would be something suitable for Travis CI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like using codeception for my acceptance tests, but regardless, the travis setup is pretty much the same. Install a selenium server!

```
language: php

php:
  - 5.6
  - 7.0
  - 7.1
  - hhvm

matrix:
  allow_failures:
    - php: hhvm

addons:
  hosts:
    - FAKEHOSTNAMEHERE

sudo: false


install:
  - wget http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar
  - composer install


before_script:
  - export DISPLAY=:99.0
  - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
  - sleep 5
  - java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -port 4444 &
  - "mysql -e 'create database codeception_test;'"
  - nohup php -S FAKEHOSTNAMEHERE:8000 public/index.php &
script:
  - php vendor/bin/codecept run  --coverage-xml --env travis
after_script:
  - phpunit --coverage-clover=coverage.clover
  - wget https://scrutinizer-ci.com/ocular.phar
  - php ocular.phar code-coverage:upload --format=php-clover tests/_output/coverage.xml
```

Just replace the `FAKEHOSTNAMEHERE` with whatever you need.

Comment: Wow, thanks. So you say I should not mock anything, but install an actual server instead? I could simply install even [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/)?

Comment: never use mamp or xampp! but sure, this allows you to run the server and run real tests with actual requests :-)

Mocking is good for testing individual units, this is good for seeing how it plays out for real

Comment: Why no MAMP / XAMPP?

Comment: because they are nothing like a real production environment! much better using vagrant and configuring it with puphpet.com, or even using docker! But anyway, Travis runs on Linux, so you want a LAMP stack. And that's just standard linux installs!

Comment: Thanks for all the references! Is there any solution that is mocking a servers programatically directly in PHP? It won't test the low-level stuff, but I could test the API anyway. Wow, Codeception just does that.

Comment: i know that codeception has a symfony module, and it mocks http requests so its super fast to test your api! depending what framework you are using, there might also be a module for that